# Скрыть иконку в панеле задач

Tags: c++, qt5

Как в qt5 скрыть иконку в панеле задач, но при этом окно должно отображаться.
В качестве окна использую класс `QMainWindow`.

---

**UPD:** Имею код создания окна:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    MainWindow w;

    w.setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    w.move(380,0);
    w.setWindowOpacity(0.6);
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Файл MainWindow.cpp

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
...
}
```

Как можно заметить я убрал рамку и отображаю окно поверх всех окон. Окно несет только информационный характер и не имеет никакого функционала (кнопок и других виджетов на нем нет, кроме `QLabel`). Весь функционал в `QSystemTrayIcon`. Меня все утраивает. Но на панеле задач отображена иконка приложения. Хочу ее убрать, сделать что-то на подобии плавающего окна, как у downloadmaster. Возможно мне следует не использовать QMainWindow? Подскажите, пжл, как убрать иконку на панеле задач или в какую сторону копать, чтобы достичь желаемого результата?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Qt::SplashScreen
```

В итоге получилось так:

```
w.setWindowFlags(Qt::SplashScreen | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
```